# Multiple command options available in one command

Tags: python

I'm working on an IRC like chatbot for connecting to an IP.Board forum and it is going to be used for games and messing around. I have a command issue that's really starting to bug me as it worked at first then started throwing errors caused by the elif part of the function. I was testing last night and it seemed to work fine, but when I booted up this morning to do some more work it started throwing the error:

```
    user, newItem = args.split("with", 1)
    ERROR requires 2 arguments but only one was specified
```

I have included the script code below.

EDIT: I fixed the issue and updated the code below to help others

```
    if cmd == "slap":
         try:
             if args == user.lower():
                    group.sendPost("-slaps "+args+" with "+random.choice(Items)+"-")
             else:
                    user, newItem = args.split("with", 1)
                    group.sendPost("-Slaps "+user+" with "+newItem+"-")
                    f = open("DictItems", "a")
                    f.write("" + newItem + '\n')
                    f.close()
         except:
                    print("Slap Command Errored with NewItem")
                    group.sendPost("I'm sorry, that command seems to be broken. I have notified the staff.")
                    self.sendPM(Yusei, "I'm sorry to inform but the slap command has failed with an error defining the newItem. Please look into it. Thank you.")
```

Comment: your write line doesn't need the initial `""` at the beginning. That's an empty string. Also I'm not sure about this but do you have two arguments to split? i.e. if you have `"foo"` it will throw an error but it's not the one you specified.

Comment: Can you provide your input that causes the error?

Comment: The command to execut it would be either .slap [insertnamehere] with [randomitem] or .slap [insertnamehere]. Also, I put the empty string there to start the input off but if it's not needed then I can remove it.

Comment: I can't recreate your error. Are you sure this is the line that's throwing the error? It's a dumb question but just checking since `def sendPost()` seems like it could have an extra argument in it that you didn't mean to add. Also, using `with open("DictItems","a") as f:` is a little cleaner and then you don't have to worry about closing your file

Comment: Yeah i'm sure. When I call the command in the chatbox (I'm testing with a localhosted site to create it) It fails to post. If you give me a second I will remove the try and except and comment the full error code.

Comment: Okay, With calling the command with .slap Rob (dummy account I included in the chat) I get this.
    user, newItem = args.split("with", 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: So in that case you don't have anything more than Rob to split and it tries to return Rob. In order for that line to work you minimally need `"Rob with chicken"`. That way there are two items to return

Comment: Yes I know that, but if you look at the first if function in the slap command It should also be able to slap with a random item from the text file, but for some reason it's ignoring that and going right to the next line. This is what's confusing me and causing it to error out

Comment: My guess would be that args is `Rob` and user.lower() is `rob` which is not equal

Comment: hmmm. That's what confuses me because I did try both thinking that this morning. I still get the same error. I even tried my original user def which was user = user.lower() with no luck either. I think i'm just gonna scrap it as it was gonna be a user input option and just create a new function for adding user inputs. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if cmd == "slap":
         try:
             if args in whitelist:
                    group.sendPost("-slaps "+args+" with "+random.choice(Items)+"-")
             else:
                    user, newItem = args.split("with", 1)
                    group.sendPost("-Slaps "+user+" with "+newItem+"-")
                    f = open("DictItems", "a")
                    f.write("" + newItem + '\n')
                    f.close()
         except:
                    print("Slap Command Errored with NewItem")
                    group.sendPost("I'm sorry, that command seems to be broken. I have notified the staff.")
                    self.sendPM(Yusei, "I'm sorry to inform but the slap command has failed with an error defining the newItem. Please look into it. Thank you.")
```

Also to the person taht notified me I could not do that, I apologise. I misread that when I looked it over. Thanks for letting me know. This is the updated code that works.

Comment: Please do not that! Add your solution as an ANSWER. Changing your code is on of the things you cannot do as defined by the help center. Please revert back and add your code as an answer. Check the help center for mor e information. Thanks.